# Problem with ticks in LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks, logarithmic-scale

When I plot some function using the Plot command, I obtain the expected result:[image]

Nevertheless, when I try to do the same but in logarithmic scale for the x axis, using LogLinearPlot, I obtain the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the figure is represented for $x\in[0,\,100]$, but when I represent it using LogLinearPlot, the x axis start from $x\approx-2$. I guess that $x=-2$ is representing $x=10^{-2}$, but I want it to show the actual value at each tick. How can I do it?

Comment: What is the value of $\log_{10}(0)$? The answer is why Mathematica doesn't start from there ;-)

Comment: I am slightly confused by your second image with ``LogLinearPlot``. What version of Mathematica are you using? Have you been changing any settings for plotting? By default, the scale should [show the actual values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi4pH.png).

Comment: MMA version 13.1 on Windows 10  gives a logarithmic x axis.

Comment: What version are you using? Also try `Plot[Tanh[x], {x, 0, 100}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}]`

Comment: Cannot reproduce your `LogLinearPlot` with Mma 13.1 on Win 10 Pro.